# Is there a less ugly way to return function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

This declaration works, but is not the most beautiful code. Is there a way to return functions less ugly? I tried `(s: String) -> writer.println(s)` but this didn't work.

```
val writeStuff: (PrintWriter) -> (String) -> Unit = {
    val writer = it
    val f: (String) -> Unit = {
        writer.println(it)
    }
    f
}
PrintWriter("test").use { writeStuff(it)("TEST") }
```

EDIT: a bit more concrete example:

```
val writeStuff: (PrintWriter) -> (String) -> Unit = { writer ->
    { writer.println(it) }
}

val sendStuff: (Any) -> (String) -> Unit = { sender ->
    { sender.equals(it) }
}

@Test fun test1() {
    val li = listOf("a", "b", "c")

    val process: List<(String) -> Unit> = 
        listOf(writeStuff(PrintWriter("a")), sendStuff(Object()))

    process.map { li.map(it) }
}
```

Comment: This code is kind of odd. Are you just trying to return a function or are you trying to do something specific with this code?

Comment: I agree with @CaseyB ... the code doesn't really make sense, can you describe the use, and we can see what options there are for the code?

Comment: @JaysonMinard: Added a bit more context. I was mostly wanting to know how you can emulate multiple parameter list

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, you can simplify your code using [lambda syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) with explicit parameter and inlining `val f`:

```
val writeStuff: (PrintWriter) -> (String) -> Unit = { writer -> 
    { writer.println(it) } 
}
```

But since Kotlin supports [local function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#local-functions) declarations, you can even make `writeStuff` a local `fun` instead of a `val`.

This would lead to the following code:

```
fun writeStuff(writer: PrintWriter): (String) -> Unit {
    return { writer.println(it) }
}
```

Or, using the [single expression syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions),

```
fun writeStuff(writer: PrintWriter): (String) -> Unit = { writer.println(it) }
```

The usage, however, will be the same:

```
PrintWriter("...").use { writeStuff(it)("...") }
```

Comment: Also note for OP, if the purpose of assigning the function to a val was to pass it to another function. It's not necessary as you can pass named functions using the syntax "::writeStuff"

Comment: When you want to pass a return value then it should look like
```fun writeStuff(writer: PrintWriter): (String) -> Int = { 
   writer.println(it) 
   1
}```
not
```fun writeStuff(writer: PrintWriter): (String) -> Int = { 
   writer.println(it) 
   return 1
}```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question while trying to figure out how to return a `Function` (the java [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)) in Kotlin. While this doesn't directly answer the question, hopefully it'll help someone else who has the same query:

```kotlin
override fun myFun(param1: Object): Function<in Object, out String?> {
    if (!param1.meetsCriteria()) 
        return Function { obj -> null }
    return Function { obj ->
        "success"
    }
}
```

In this case, I was overriding a method in a java interface that required me to return a `Function` instance. (Note that since the param is not used in my particular implementation above, I could remove it and just have the return result. eg `return Function { null }`)

Edit: After some research, it turns out Kotlin covers this subject with their discussion on "SAM (single abstract method) conversions" [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#sam-conversions), though it may not be the most intuitive thing to look up when figuring out how to return `Function`s.